# Word usage: "percent" or "percentage"

Tags: word-choice

What would be the correct form here:

> Set size in percent
>
> Set size in percentage

Comment: Set size as a percentage _of what_? Getting the right choice of wording is usually determined by context.

Comment: size of an image

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/whats-the-difference-between-percent-of-and-percentage-of/395326#395326

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy; the word 'percent' always follows a number: three percent, fifteen percent, 'The answer is 34 percent.'

The word percentage is used when there is no number mentioned/being used: 'What is the percentage?', 'The percentage is the number divided by the total.', 'I'm bad at calculating percentages.'

And so I'd say your answer is the second one.

Hope that helps! :)